# Dropzone Tree panel to View

Tags: extjs, treepanel

I am trying to implement some drag and drop functionallity from a Tree Panel to a View but I have not been able to do this. I am new using ExtJs and maybe I am doing something wrong.
I have my tree defined like this:

```
var treeMeasures = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    id: 'treeMeasuresPanel',
    title: 'Measures',
    region: 'north',
    store: dsMeasures,
    rootVisible: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '50%',
    useArrows: true,
    enableDD: true,
    allowDrop: false,
    collapsible: true,
    border: 0,
    style: 'border-right:1px solid #99BCE8;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom: none;',
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            render: initializeFieldsDragZone
        },
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            ddGroup: 'fieldsToAreas',
            enableDrag: true,
            enableDrop: false,
            containerScroll: true
        }
    }
});
```

The initializeFieldsDragZone function:

```
function initializeFieldsDragZone(v, record, item, index, evt, eOpts) {
v.dragZone = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DragZone', v.getEl(), {

    getDragData: function (e) {
        var sourceEl = e.getTarget(v.itemSelector, 10), d;
        if (sourceEl) {
            d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
            d.id = Ext.id();
            return v.dragData = {
                sourceEl: sourceEl,
                repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY(),
                ddel: d,
                controlData: v.getRecord(sourceEl).data
            };
        }
    },

    //      Provide coordinates for the proxy to slide back to on failed drag.
    //      This is the original XY coordinates of the draggable element.
    getRepairXY: function () {
        return this.dragData.repairXY;
    }
});
```

}

The View:

```
 var filterAreaView = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: dsFilterArea,
    tpl: "",
    ddGroup: 'fieldsToAreas',
    bodyStyle: {
        background: 'ffffff'
    },
    listeners: {
            render: initializeAreasDropZone
        }        
});
```

And the initializeAreasDropZone function is:

```
function initializeAreasDropZone(area) {
var view = area.getEl();

view.dropZone = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropZone', area.el, {

    getTargetFromEvent: function (e) {
        return e.getTarget('.x-grid-row');
    },

    onNodeEnter: function (target, dd, e, data) {

    },

    onNodeOut: function (target, dd, e, data) {

    },

    onNodeOver: function (target, dd, e, data) {
        return true;
    },

    onNodeDrop: function (target, dd, e, data) {
```

//            My Code

```
        return true;
    }
});
```

}

And the problem is that when I drag the node from the tree and try to drop into the view nothing happens.

Does anyone knows if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Alberto

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't have anything to do with dropzone.js (www.dropzonejs.com)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be overthinking this.  I created a working model of DD between two panels (Ext.tree.Panel) each containing a root, with multiple folders, and multiple leaves in each folder.  Simply by adding the plugin to each tree enabled DD:

```
viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            ddGroup: 'myDDGroup',
            appendOnly: true,
            sortOnDrop: true,
            containerScroll: true
        }
    },
```

After doing this, when I click and drag a leaf from one tree to the other, it dutifully adds the leaf to the target folder upon release of the mouse button.  I didn't have to do anything else as far as monitoring events.

Answer (score 0):

if you use TreePanel for Drag Zone, i think we don't need to create function initializeFieldsDragZone, just use plugin "treeviewdragdrop".

The problem from your code is initializeAreasDropZone must have ddgroup same as the plugin:

```
 function initializeAreasDropZone(area) {
    var view = area.getEl();

    view.dropZone = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropZone', area.el, {

        getTargetFromEvent: function (e) {
            return e.getTarget('.x-grid-row');
        },

        onNodeEnter: function (target, dd, e, data) {

        },

        onNodeOut: function (target, dd, e, data) {

        },

        onNodeOver: function (target, dd, e, data) {
            return true;
        },

        onNodeDrop: function (target, dd, e, data) {
            console.log(data);
        },

        ddGroup: 'fieldsToAreas'
    });
}
```

cheers